# GCP Monitoring drop-down menu

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I'd like to have just one dashboard containing all namespaces and services and a metric such as *traffic request count*. However, given that we have several namespaces and services in our system, I'd like to have a drop-down menu in the chart so that I could filter by namespace and service, for example *namespace = x*, and *service = y and z*. Is it possible to do so in GCP Monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure with regards to the specific filter you are looking for. But you can check this official documentation on [Managing charts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts) for Cloud Monitoring.

You can add images to your post and also provide what GCP service you are using for a  better understanding of your post.